# How to access object attribute from nested object function?

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
var myObj = new Object({
data: {
    val_a: 1, 
    val_b: 2
},

myfuncs: {
    first_func: function() {
        this.data.val_b = 3;
    }
}
});
```

why does this fail:

```
myObj.myfuncs.first_func()
```

with error:

> VM154:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'val_b' of undefined
>       at Object.first_func (:9:20)
>       at :1:15

but this works:

```
myObj.data.val_b
```

And what's the correct way to access data.val_b from first_func?

Comment: `this.data.val_b = 3;` is not using the right context, `this` is related to first_func's context rather than myObj's context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the call to `first_func`, `this` refers to `myObj.myfuncs`, not `myObj`. More: [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Since your object is a one-off, you can just use `myObj` instead:

```js
var myObj = {
  data: {
    val_a: 1,
    val_b: 2
  },
  myfuncs: {
    first_func: function() {
      myObj.data.val_b = 3;
    }
  }
};
myObj.myfuncs.first_func();
console.log(myObj.data.val_b); // 3
```

(Note that the call to `new Object` is neither necessary or desirable. Just use the result of the object initializer (`{...}`) directly.)

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve access to `this.` is to use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which does not create its own `this.`
In your example `first_func: function() {` created a new `this.`

```js
var myObj = new Object({
  data: {
    val_a: 1,
    val_b: 2
  },
  myfuncs: {
    first_func: () => {
      this.myObj.data.val_b = 3;
    }
  }
});
myObj.myfuncs.first_func();
console.log(myObj.data.val_b); // 3
```